# Create a View Linking to Content

Tags: views, 8

I'm new to Drupal in general and am having some trouble with creating a view to display and link the information I want.

I have a content type called Project. This content type has a boolean called "Project Status" where "true" is labelled as "In Progress" and "false" is "Completed".

I want to create a block view to use as a sidebar on my page that lists all projects where the project status is true, and links to those projects by their title. I can make the view display the list of the projects that are in progress, but I can't figure out how to make it link back to those projects.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need to add a filter under "Filter Criteria" in your view settings and choose "true" for that field.

Comment: @NiallMurphy: Thanks. I did this before, but it was just showing the titles in plain text. I must have changed another setting when I tried before. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In Views. In your title field config, there is a check box that says link to content. This is checked by default. I guess u must have unchecked it.

Comment: Ya, that would be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue was in the "Fields" section of the view. If you click the "Content: Title" field, there's a checkbox to link to the content. I suspect this wasn't checked in the view that I was having trouble with, but it is enabled by default.

[image: Content:Title checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

The title field will have an option on its settings to "Link this field to its content". Check off that box and save the view, and the titles should be linked to their node detail page.

Comment: Thanks - I've had a look and it's actually in "Fields > Content:Title" where there's the "Link to Content" checkbox. Unfortunately I deleted the initial view already that I was having issues with, so I can't check if that was the cause or not for my original issue, but I've got it working now.